Searching for the name of a 70s/80s teenager scifi TV series/film with funnel-eared aliens/robots, europe
I really don't remember much of it. But it boggles my mind for about a decade now. It ran on German TV. Probably ARD or ZDF. Late 70s or early 80s.
It's a series or a movie with aliens. If it's a series, it doesn't have many parts. Movie made for TV is more likely. The humanoid kinda faceless aliens have funnel ears and there's one scene where one of the young heroes almost gets turned into an alien by means of some kind of mold (the mold even has funnel ears built in). He's in a lab of the aliens and his friends rescue him. The machine that was about to turn him into an alien or robot held him fixed on one half of the mold. It might have been that he and the bottom half was to the left and the top half was to the right. My picture might not be accurate.
Another feature of that movie where teleporter doors with a frame and nothing else, standing around in the open. They worked similar to Matrix Reloaded, you could open them and they would show another place inside.
If I had to guess, I'd think it was either from an eastern country like czechoslovakia or, also possible, a british movie.
The teens weren't in street clothes, more like a grey? uniform or stylish clothes that screamed scifi for the time. They might have belonged to a group of explorers because I faintly remember an older guy in the same clothes. But it's more than 30 years ago, so unless someone knows hypnosis...


I'm sure I've seen this question before. Did you already ask it here?

Yes, I asked it two months ago and checked regularly. Then a moderator killed it on a whim. Do you guys know of any less hostile place to find an answer? Because the mods in here are pretty eager to create an anti-fan.

@Haunt_House I'm afraid that's just standard procedure. ID questions without any activity might be deleted after 30 days. Please don't take it personally, and thanks for adding those nifty drawings. :) Voting to reopen.

I'm sorry that you found this place hostile :(  Your question was deemed off topic for this site when you asked it before, I guess.  Please don't be discouraged by that.  You took the time to add more information...and hand drawn pics no less!  +1!  Vote to reopen :)

Well, I even put a bounty on the old one. Problem is, only old farts like me (40+) will remember that show. And they're less likely to come here.

Don't kid yourself.  There are plenty of old farts around here :P

Thank you for your answer. Sorry, I know Lexx and that show has been filmed about 15 to 20 years later, partly with CGI. I know the scene you mention. I am completely positive about the old age of the movie/show.

If it was a TV show from the UKofGB&NI, and your recollection was somewhat distorted due to passing of time, then could it possibly have been Thames TV  "The Tommorrow People" story arc "The Slaves of Jedekiah".  The green cyclops had strange ears and teleportation via a door occurs several times.  http://thetomorrowpeople.wikia.com/wiki/The_Slaves_of_Jedikiah

Check out episodes on Youtube ---    YouTube   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7mixZQughd0

Thanks for the link. I still check here and there. While the tomorrow people fit the time, I am pretty sure that wasn't it. I could be wrong, but I am not at all sure the show had people with ordinary clothes in it. No cyclops in it. And while I think my memory isn't completely distorted, I'm sure I am in for quite a surprise ( :
